# React FullCalendar - can't return custom JSX on date selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Currently, I have the calendar setup to return a material-ui popover when an event is clicked on. This is done using the `eventContent` property. I have tried to the do the same when a day or time is clicked but haven't had any luck. I have the interactions plugin installed and imported (this can be seen when I click on the events and get back logs shown below). Apart from select, I've also tried `dateClick`. For Context, both `RenderDayClickedAction` and `RenderAppointmentClickedActions` are the same component but with different names currently.

```html
<FullCalendar
                    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                    slotMinTime="08:00:00"
                    slotMaxTime="20:00:00"
                    selectable={true}
                    headerToolbar={{
                        left: "prev,next today",
                        center: "title",
                        right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
                    }}
                    events={events}
                    select={(info) => {
                      <!-- this logs -->
                        console.log({ info }); 
                      
                      <!-- this does not fire -->
                        return ( 
                            <RenderDayClickedActions
                                eventContent={info}
                                setSelectedEvent={setSelectedEvent}
                                setModalAction={setModalAction}
                                setOpen={setOpen}
                            />
                        );
                    }}
                    eventContent={(info) => {
                        return (
                           <!-- this works just fine as intended -->
                            <RenderAppointmentClickedActions
                                eventContent={info}
                                setSelectedEvent={setSelectedEvent}
                                setModalAction={setModalAction}
                                setOpen={setOpen}
                            />
                        );
                    }}
                />
```

Here is what I get when I click on an event which I'm also hoping to get when I click on an empty date.

[image: expected result when I click on an empty date]

Comment: I don't know react specifically, but I suspect the difference is that fullCalendar's eventContent expects you to return some HTML and will use it, but select and dateClick don't. You need to append the html (or apply the appropriate JavaScript events) to the element provided in the info object, rather then returning it.

Comment: I explored this avenue as well, but I wasn't exactly sure where to put it. From their docs it seems that they expose multiple areas for content injections but they ONLY talk about conentEvent and don't list out where these "various areas" would be located.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection

Comment: If you go to https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc and look for anything described as "render hooks" then those are the areas which follow the content injection pattern. select and dateClick aren't part of that model. They can't be really, because they have to do something different each time depending on what exactly what clicked on. You need to make your code do an action when those events occur, rather than just show some pre-prepared content. e.g. make it do something to show a modal or a popup based on what was clicked.

Comment: You might be able to attach something to days using the date render hooks, but it doesn't give you the flexibility of "select", where it allows the user to drag and select specific times, and then you're told exactly what times they selected (rather than just a whole day). So you need to write code inside "select" which will open a modal popup (or similar) when the selection is made. I'm not sure how you do that in React, as I've never used it. In native JS it would be fairly simple just to show a new div or something.